# Unsuccesful Google search for "euclidean geometry proof of collinearity"

Tags: geometry

I am looking for a clear explanation of techniques one might use for proving collinearity. It's easy in coordinate geometry and with vectors. My question is: in Euclidean Geometry what precisely is required to prove collinearity? I'd like a statement such as: A, B and C are collinear iff {condition}.

Comment: I think, what you're asking for is not really "a proof" but "a definition" or "usage". Otherwise the answer would be something along the line: *"it can be proved given you have the euclidean coordinates"* or so. Perhaps you want to adapt the title of the question?

Comment: One of the following is true: $$\begin{align}|AB|&=|AC|+|CB|\\ |BC|&=|BA|+|AC| \\ |CA| &= |CB|+|BA|\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Strictly spoken, *A,B,C* are collinear if you need only *1* dimension in 3D to locate them all; in other words: if they lay on one straight line. It can be more intuitively be shown if translation and rotation (always of the complete set of points(!)) in the 3D-space is allowed: then it is possible, that they all have only one nonzero coordinate (on the x-axis, for instance).

More usual in statistics is, however, that it needs not only a reduction down to 1 dimension (one line) but it is common to talk of "collinearity" even if 3 or more points populate a plane - although strictly spoken one should call this "coplanarity", and further, if there are *4* points *A,B,C,D* and one needs only *3* dimensions of *4* to call this "cosphericity" and so on. Just, if the required number of dimensions to represent the whole set of points is at least one less than the number of points, it is in general spoken of "collinearity".

---

One possible single criterion: if the rank of the matrix of the coordinates is deficient. Or: if the rank of the matrix of the coordinates is smaller than the number of points.
"collinear" in the strict sense: if the ranks is equal to 1.